# Any way to place the Menu Bar in Win7's Windows Explorer above the Address Bar?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Pretty much what the question says.  I want to put the menu bar above the navigation/address bar (contains the back and forward buttons, etc) just so that I have a consistent user experience in the programs I use.  Tried Googling around but I can't find anything definitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Windows Explorer in Windows 7.

You can see when looking at an Explorer windows that the menu bar appears within the Window but the navigation and address part appears to be *part* of the window.

The only thing that could be done would be to build a different explorer.